# print last line of a file and append a value using awk

Tags: bash, awk, append, gawk

I have a python script which outputs data x and y to the file `averages.dat` in two columns.

I'm trying to use awk to take the last line of `averages.dat`, add a value in a new 3rd column then append this to the file `averages2.dat`.

I've been trying `awk END{print} averages.dat` to get the last line and

`awk '{print $0, value}' averages.dat` to append a value to the end in a third column.

Both of these work fine on their own but I've tried combining them to no avail. I know I'll need to use `>> averages2.dat` at the end to append to the new file.

Any advice on combining these two awk commands? Or is there a better way to get the last line than `END{print}`? because I feel like that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
awk 'END { print $0, value }' averages.dat >> averages2.dat
```

`END` is to be understood as the condition under which the block behind it is executed; thus this executes `print $0, value` if the end of the input has been reached. This is the case only when the last record is being processed.

To use a shell variable in the script, write

```
awk -v density="$DENSITY" 'END { print $0, density }' averages.dat >> averages2.dat
```

this sets the awk variable `density` to the value of `$DENSITY` before the awk code starts running.

In such cases, awk is more robust than sed because with sed you have to substitute your variable directly into the code (such as `"s/.*/& $DENSITY/"`). sed will then end up interpreting it as code, not data, which means that if it contains characters that have special meaning for sed (such as `&`), sed will error out or do strange things. Awk can handle this without problem using the above invocation.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error but it's my problem. My `value` is actually ${DENSITY} flag because it changes for every iteration in a loop in a bash script. Can awk still do this? Your answer works perfect for a single non-changing value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -n '$s/.*/& value/p' file
```

#### Explanation:

- `-i.bak` - Use inline editing and use `.bak` extension to save original file
- `-n` - Suppress printing
- `$s` - Substitute only last line
- `.*` - Match full line
- `& value`  - Use full line in replacement followed by a space and literal "value"
- `p`  - Print replacement line

Comment: so in my case it you be like `sed -i.bak -n '$s/.*/& value/p' averages.dat >> averages2.dat` ? Thanks for the breakdown @anubhava

Comment: You don't need `>> averages2.dat` is you want to edit the `averages.dat` with changed line since `-i.bak` does that already. This is one advantage of `sed` over `awk`